# Php MySql Statement using multiple AND Operators

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to write a php mysql statement using multiple AND Operators and can't seem to get it to work.  Is there a simple fix for this?

```
$sql = 'SELECT user_id FROM groups WHERE group_id = 11 AND group_id = 17 AND group_id = 19 AND group_id = 20';
$res = mysqli_query($gmg_conn, $sql);
```

This query has to return each user that is in all of the groups mentioned.  For example the DB table looks as follows.

```
group_id | user_id  
11       | 800  
17       |  800  
19       |  800  
20       |  800
```

So as you can see if I run this query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT user_id FROM groups WHERE group_id IN (11,17,19,20)';
```

It will return all users that are in 1 of those groups.  I need something that will search for users who are apart of all 4 groups. The other method I have is to bring in each user 1 by 1 and pull their groups and then do the if statement in php but I would like to seek a MySql query for this if possible.

@Alex who is located in the comments section was able to help me with exactly what I needed.

```
SELECT (COUNT(group_id) = 3) AS matches, user_id AS user 
FROM groups 
WHERE group_id IN (12, 18, 14) 
GROUP BY user_id HAVING matches <> 0;
```

Comment: Think about what you're asking MySQL to do: find rows that have group_id 11 AND 17 - that is not possible. A row can't have both. Are you looking for `OR`?

Comment: (Base axiom: The WHERE applies to a *single* record at a time.)

Comment: `HAVING COUNT([DISTINCT] group_id) = 4`

Answer (score 2):

When MySQL runs your query it would evaluate like this:

```
Table (assume only 3 records exist):
====================================
group_id 
11         <-- Contains 11 AND 17 AND 19 AND 20? FALSE
17         <-- Contains 11 AND 17 AND 19 AND 20? FALSE
19         <-- Contains 11 AND 17 AND 19 AND 20? FALSE
```

What you want to use is the `OR` operator or `IN` method, this causes the evaluation to happen like this:

```
Table (assume only 3 records exist):
====================================
group_id 
11         <-- Contains 11 OR 17 OR 19 OR 20       ? TRUE (Or query)
17         <-- Value In collection (11, 17, 19, 20)? TRUE (In query)
19         <-- Contains 11 OR 17 OR 19 OR 20       ? TRUE (Or query)
```

Therefore your amended query would look like:

```
SELECT user_id FROM groups WHERE group_id IN (11,17,19,20)
```

OR

```
SELECT user_id FROM groups WHERE group_id = 11 OR group_id = 17 OR group_id = 19 OR group_id = 20
```

Under the hood, the IN() method handles the OR chaining for you, therefore I'd recommend the first implementation.

**EDIT** In order to get all users which belong to each of the specified groups, you can utilise a COUNT method and then perform a check in the GROUP BY segment:

```
SELECT (COUNT(group_id) = 3) AS matches, user_id AS user 
FROM groups 
WHERE group_id IN (12, 18, 14) 
GROUP BY user_id HAVING matches <> 0;
```

Alternatively this query would work too:

```
SELECT user_id AS user 
FROM groups 
WHERE group_id IN (12, 18, 14) 
GROUP BY user_id HAVING (COUNT(group_id) = 3);
```

Lets break this down so you can understand it

**Line 1:** (COUNT(group_id) = 3) - this will return 1 (true) if the query returns a value which is 3 (or whatever the size of your collection is)

**Line 3:** Performs the OR check we saw earlier, but will only return 1 if the COUNT is 3

**Line 4:** List the users who match the criteria, ONLY when 1 is returned (<> is the != operator in SQL)

I hope this helps you - Updated [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94810/54) :)

Comment: I tried this query and it isn't what I can use.  Please check my updated question for further explanation and more information and thank you for your help.

Comment: I got the fiddle to work perfectly and that is exactly what I need however when I run the query in phpMyAdmin I'm getting this Error: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row.  Do you have any idea as to why this is coming up?

Comment: Alex, this worked perfectly, I want to thank you for all your help and knowledge.  I have taken the liberty of updating the question to reflect your answer.

Comment: You're most welcome - if this was the correct answer please consider accepting it as the answer or up-voting it for future readers.  Good luck with your application! :)

Answer (score 1):

use the IN operator.

`$sql = 'SELECT user_id FROM groups WHERE group_id IN (11,17,19,20)';
$res = mysqli_query($gmg_conn, $sql);`

It's because it's looking for group_id that has all 4 values set at once, so it wont show any results.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `WHERE group_id IN (11, 17, 19, 20);`, your current query isn't logically possible because a field can not have multiple values at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Did someone tell you that 'and' means that both condition should be matched?

in your case you should either use 'or' because if `group_id` is 11 it cannot be 17 and hence in any case it fails. But to rewrite your query it is better to use `in`

`SELECT user_id FROM groups WHERE group_id in (11, 17, 19,20)`

Hope that help